# Javascript: DOMParser.parseFromString() method returns only 1428 XmlNodes, but the actual Xml has 1728 nodes? What is going wrong?

Tags: javascript, xml

Generated XML Document has  node with text 'error on line 1 at column 524289: AttVal: ' expected. Even though there is no single quote present at position 524289 and the entire XML is valid.

[image]

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: please check embeded image. It contains XML output and javascript code that I am using

Comment: don't post a cropped image of your javascript... post your javascript

Comment: I am using below javascript:   function callMe(id)
    {
        if (window.ActiveXObject == undefined) {
            var parser = new DOMParser();
            var xml = parser.parseFromString(document.getElementById(id).value, "application/xhtml+xml");
    }
}    Please click on the image to check xml parseerror I am getting